# Open a page with string as a valid URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user do a search, I'm passing the user's search word as the string to direct a user to a new page. My question is how to create a valid url (e.g. prevent spaces on the string)?

It's important that the next page is able to identify where search word spaces were from the `string` (if there were any spaces).

This is what I have so far:

```
window.location.href = "/furniture/info.html?furn="+user search word
```

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has a `encodeURIComponent()` which can be used for exactly this purpose.

```
var someString = 'hey there';
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(someString);
var newURL = 'yourdomain.com/'+encodedString;
```

Comment: Yep :) You may already be aware, but the 'inspector' in chrome and firefox are great tools for testing this stuff yourself.